# Download or get the original Image name from ImageId in a Collection in Rekognition

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, face-recognition, amazon-rekognition

After doing a Face search in a collection in rekognition I want to download the images but I am not able to because as you know a collection stores ImageId instead of the Image Name is there a way to extract the original image name from the ImageId provided because that will solve my problem. I am not using ExternalImageId because there are some restrictions for naming the externalImageid in a collection. I want to extract the original image name from the Imageid provided.

Comment: @Hashir Baig Have you solved this problem yet can you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Rekognition stores the "features vector" of your imagen, and discards the image itself. So I cannot see it working the way you want